# template not looked at app level template directory in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-settings

I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /link/

link_app/link_list.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/link/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
link_app/link_list.html
```

Inside my `link_app`, I have a `templates` folder in which I have placed `link_list.html`

I have also included the following in my `setting.py`

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
   'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

I also have a `templates` folder that is common to project (not to app) for which I have

`TEMPLATE_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)` in the `settings.py`

EDIT:
from the error, it seems to look for `list_html` at
`link_app/link_list.html`

but it must be looking at `link_app/templates/link_list.html`

Project-Structure:

```
LinkDjangoProject
     link_project
     link_app
          templates
             link_list.html
     templates
     manage.py
```

Comment: Is link_app in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @Greg yes, for sure, it is in my Installed_apps

Comment: What is your project directory stricture?

Comment: @frnhr: I have updated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard project structure (partial) is this:

```
projectname
  |
  |-projectname  <-- settings.py, etc.
  |
  |-someapp
    |
    |-templates
      |
      |-someapp  <-- templates that are referenced with "someapp/a_template.html" go inside this directory
      |
      ...
```

I suspect you are missing the `someapp` directory inside your `projectname/someapp/templates` directory.

---

This structure allows templates from one app to be overridden in another app, provided the overriding app is placed before the original app in the `INSTALED_APPS` list in `settings.py`

Similar directory structure is used with static and/or media files as well.